# One-off error(?) on Reactjs setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
console.log(newState);
this.setState(newState);
this.validateFieldsAndUpdateForm(type);
console.log(this.state);
```

When I log out `newState` and `this.state` after the above executes, it appears that the changes have not held until I hit this again with a new change to the state.

```
newState = {
    contact:
        firstName: “joe”
        lastName: “schmoe”
}

this.state = {
    contact:
        firstName: “joe”
        lastName: “”
}
```

I think I need a callback here so that I only execute the second command once `newState` overrides `this.state`.

```
this.setState(newState, this.validateFieldsAndUpdateForm(type));
```

it adds newState to state, so this.state looks like this:

```
{
    contact: 
    newState:
        contact:
}
```

Also the callback is not executed, which makes me believe I’ve injected it wrong.
How can I make the `contact` of the `newState` to override the original contact NOW and not on the next call to `setState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're running into this issue is because `this.setState` is not guaranteed to execute immediately.  From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

You're correct that you can pass in a function as a callback to execute immediately after the state change occurs, but you aren't quite doing that.

```
this.setState(newState, this.validateFieldsAndUpdateForm(type));
```

This is executing the function `this.validateFieldsAndUpdateForm(type)` immediately, whereas you want to pass in a callback to be executed after the state transition.  So what you're looking for is something like this:

```
this.setState(newState, function () {
    this.validateFieldsAndUpdateForm(type);
});
```

That should solve that issue.  I am not sure how to interpret the last part of your question.  If you could clarify in a comment, I will edit my answer to help.

Comment: Got it. What would this look like in es6? Struggling with the function syntax.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks Michael.   `this.setState(newState, () => {
        this.validateFieldsAndUpdateForm(type);
      });`

Comment: Was just about to edit my answer with that, haha.  Glad to help!